# Have a different language field on a Dynamics CRM form

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

Is there any way to have a "single line of text" field with a different language than the base language on a custom entity form? I have a text field "Channel Name" and I need to have another field "Channel Name in Arabic". Explaining a bit, I want it such that when the user types in the field, it should be in Arabic and not the base language English. Please help.

Comment: Tag the actual version of your crm to make it easier for people to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts of CRM are translatable, while others are not.

- You *can* translate the label for a field into a user's local language.
- You *cannot* translate the contents of a text field: The same content will be shown to all users, irrespective or their language settings.

There is nothing stopping your users from entering Arabic into any text field in CRM if that fits your needs.